# Generic type isn't picked up

Tags: rust

Hi rust noob here and still in learning phase. Im trying to create a stuct with a method that will return a new instance of it. The value of the struct is generic. Can be a bool or a u32. Rust doesn't compile and complaints that the return value of the method is not the correct type.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Matrix<T> {
    matrix: HashMap<String, T>,
}

impl<T> Matrix<T> {
    fn new<I>(rows: u32, columns: u32, initial_value: I) -> Matrix<I> {
        let mut matrix = HashMap::new();

        for rowCount in 0..rows {
            for columnCount in 0..columns {
                matrix.insert(format!("{},{}", rowCount, columnCount), false);
            }
        }

        Matrix { matrix }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let matrix: Matrix<bool> = Matrix::new(3, 3, false);
}
```

The output is

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:18
   |
8  |     fn new<I>(rows: u32, columns: u32, initial_value: I) -> Matrix<I> {
   |            - this type parameter
...
17 |         Matrix { matrix }
   |                  ^^^^^^ expected type parameter `I`, found `bool`
   |
   = note: expected struct `HashMap<_, I>`
              found struct `HashMap<_, bool>`
```

Im not sure what should I do. I don't understand why rust is not considering I as a generic. Im pretty sure Im missing some basic syntax.

[Here is a link to the code.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b677abe4e4ad63c82b0c142891663b62)

Comment: You're always inserting the Boolean value `false` into the hashmap. Surely you meant this to be `initial_value`?

Comment: Oh i missed that. yes it should be inital_value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `new` is defined to return `Matrix<I>` per its signature but the implementation always returns `Matrix<bool>`. If you called `Matrix::new` with a `u32` instead of the `bool` in `main`, you'd be violating the signature.

If you change the `insert` call in `new` to insert the `initial_value`, you'll be creating the correct type to return from `Matrix::new` but you'll still get other compilation errors.

Firstly, `impl<T> Matrix<T> {}` defines a generic parameter `T` on the whole impl block. The compiler has no way to fill in this parameter on your `new` call since it doesn't return `Matrix<T>` and doesn't bind `T` in any other way. You can work around this in two ways, one just mentioned for completeness' sake, the other probably being the way to go:

1. Ascribe the instantiation of `T` on `Matrix::new` as `Matrix::<()>::new(...)`. The `()` unit type is just used as a dummy since it has no effect.
2. The proper solution: remove `I` on `Matrix::new` and use `T` for `initial_value` instead. `T` is then defined by the caller and binds the value type of the wrapped `HashMap` to the caller's instantiation.

After fixing the type resolution issue, you'll run into yet another issue: You're repeatedly using `initial_value` in the loop but it's neither `Clone` nor `Copy + Clone`. If you add a `where T: Copy + Clone` on `Matrix::new`, your code should compile.

Comment: Ah thanks I have gotten the code to compile now. I originally tried with option 2 but I got an error `T already used`. If you change the below code to T you will get the error. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=25ed577ca158918dbeae2c668da50e84

Comment: You need to remove the `T` from `new` since it's already declared on the impl block. `fn new(rows: u32, columns: u32, initial_value: T) -> Matrix<T> where T: Copy + Clone` and the dummy `::<()>` needs to go: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f397f22b6cc1c9fcb7afc1318b0b7362

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot. Learned a bit more today.